# node.js server that sends html+css+js as response combined

Tags: node.js

I am trying to create a simple server using node (I AM NEW TO NODE.JS)

1. server is working.
2. able to read content of html, css and js file
3. the problem I am facing is server only returns me the html file on url (localhost:8000)
4. if I enter the url : localhost:8000/css, it returns me the data of css file that is actual code.
5. same with localhost:8000/js, return me the code.
6. I want it to return me the complete page using html,css and js.

please guide me here ..

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs'); 

var htmlData, cssData, jsData;

fs.readFile('index.html',(err, data)=>{
  if(err){
    htmlData = err;
  }
    htmlData = data;
});

fs.readFile('style.css',(err, data)=>{
  if(err){
    cssData = err;
  }
    cssData = data;
});

fs.readFile('index.js',(err, data)=>{
  if(err){
    jsData = err;
  }
    jsData = data;
});

const httpServer = http.createServer(serverHandler);

function serverHandler(req, res) {
  // add a HTTP header:
   switch (req.url) {
    case '/':
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      res.write(htmlData); //read the file & write the data content
      res.end();
      break;
    
    case '/style':
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/css'});
      res.write(cssData); //read the file & write the data content
      res.end();
      break;   
    
    case '/js':
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/js'});
      res.write(jsData); //read the file & write the data content
      res.end();
      break;  

    default:
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
      res.write('error'); //read the file & write the data content
      res.end();
      break;
   }   
  }

  httpServer.listen(8000,()=>{console.log("PORT is 8000")});
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform for specific programming questions. _"please guide me here"_ isn't a specific programming question.

Answer (score 0):

You almost reached the goal by yourself.
Just put actual filenames into your `switch case` statement like this:
edit `case '/js':` to `case '/index.js'`
and for css `case '/style':` to `case '/style.css':`.

Your http requests should match the actual names of files.